# Magento2: Can we add current URL in "Scripts and Style Sheets"?

Tags: magento2, head, canonical

I want to add Dynamic URL in Admin->Content->Design->Configuration->HTML Head->Scripts and Style Sheets?

Actually, I want to add canonical tag throughout the website.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="canonical" src="CurrentUrl here" />
```

Another way to add this is the XML file.

```
<head>
  <link rel="canonical" src="CurrentUrl here" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```

Please give me the clue if anyone used this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want set that value dynamically, you have to with PHP. You only can be use static url like {{media_url}} or {{base_url}}.
You can create a new module for doing dynamically and do the next:

> Namespace/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="after.body.start">
             <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Content\Head\Canonical" name="vendor.namespace.head.canonical" template="Namespace_Module::head/canonical.phtml" />
         </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates/head/canonical.phtml

```
<?php /** @var \Namespace\Module\Block\Content\Head\Canonical $block */?>
<?php if ($block->getCanonicalUrl()): ?>
    <link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $block->getCanonicalUrl(); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

> Namespace/Module/Block/Content/Head/Canonical.php

```
...

public function getCanonicalUrl(){
   ...
}

...
```

Comment: Added same, But my phtml file not called. Block file called. But phtml file not called.

Comment: Use <referenceBlock name="header"> instead of <referenceContainer name="header">.

Comment: @Ravi sorry, I have updated my response with the new layout.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated <referenceBlock name="after.body.start">  to  <referenceBlock name="head.additional">